# Using sqlalchemy and context manager the database is not updating

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I am trying to update a database using sqlalchemy and I need the connection/session to be closed after the execution of the script to be used by another action (delete). I rewrite a part of a previous code (not mine) and I tried both of codes below but unfortunately nothing new is written in the database. It is not updating the database with a new value if I check with Database Browser or by the code (with lookup function).

Thank you very much by advance

First code I tried:

```
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import logging


logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

Base = declarative_base()
path1=os.getcwd()
datastore_file = os.path.join(
        path1,
        '../mydatabase.db'
    )
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(datastore_file))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class ComponentValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'component_value'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

class ThingOne(object):
    def go(self, session,ct):
        (session.query(ComponentValue).filter(ComponentValue.value == ct.value)).first()
def lookup(ct):
    session = Session()
    try:
        val =ThingOne().go(session,ct) 
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
    return val

def update(ct):
    session = Session()
    try:
        val = ThingOne().go(session,ct)

        if not val and len(ct.value.strip()):
            val = ComponentValue(value=ct.value)
            session.add(val)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Second code I also tried:

```
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

Base = declarative_base()

path1=os.getcwd()
datastore_file = os.path.join(
        path1,
        '../mydatabase.db'
    )

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(datastore_file))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)

class ComponentValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'component_value'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

class ThingOne(object):
    def go(self, session,ct):
        (session.query(ComponentValue).filter(ComponentValue.value == ct.value)).first()

def lookup(ct):
    with session_scope() as session:
        val =ThingOne().go(session,ct)        
        return val

def update(ct):
    with session_scope() as session:
        val = ThingOne().go(session,ct)
        if not val and len(ct.value.strip()):
            val = ComponentValue(value=ct.value)
            session.add(val)
        session.commit()
```

Comment: The presented code does not actually use `contextmanager`. And what does "does not update correctly" mean?

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. I updated my question, I tried with and without the context manager but in both cases the database was not updated (No new value added by checking with a dbbrowser).

Comment: Have you double checked that the branch `if not val and len(ct.value.strip())` is taken? Just trying to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Yes it is taken. The most surprising is if the db is open with a dbbrowser and I run my python program I get an error that the db is already in use by another program (dbbrowser). So it means that the python program really try to write in this db, right ?

Comment: `ThingOne.go` doesn't return anything.